# cardinality of the set of all partitions of N which contain only finite sets

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, set-partition

Cardinality of the set of all partitions of N which contain only finite sets?
My intuition tells me c would be the answer but don't know how to proof that.

Comment: As a suggestion:  to any such partition, associate a binary "decimal" by putting a $1$  at any slot which starts a new block in the partition.  Thus $1=.\overline 1$ would be associated with the partition in which each natural number is its own block.

Comment: In other words you are finding the cardinality of cofinite subset on $\mathbb{N}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Picking the minimum member of each partition set gives us an infinite subset of $\Bbb N$ and all infinite subsets of $\Bbb N$ can be made that way from some partition with finite sets.

The powerset of $\Bbb N$ has $\frak{c}$ member sets and only $\aleph_0$ of them are finite, so the set of infinite subsets of $\Bbb N$ also has size $\mathfrak{c}$..